# Photorec not seeing SD memory of camera

Tags: 11.10, command-line, files, data-recovery

I am trying to recover pictures form a friends SD memory camera. When I connect the camera and run photorec it is not seeing the camera as a drive for me to recover files from. It only shows my hard drive.

Is there anyway I can force it to see my camera?

Comment: Check if it shows up in `lsusb`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try mounting the card using something other then your camera - a card reader or maybe another camera.

Some cameras use [PTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) so they're not mounted as a normal [USB mass-storage device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class) though it may look similar from Nautilus. Because of that, photorec has no direct access to the card's filsystem, so it can't recover anything.

Comment: hmmm, I dont have a card reader on me....

Comment: well, at least you could google the model of the camera to see if it supports PTP or mass-storage protocol. Older cameras supported PTP only more often

Comment: thanks will try that, and maybe try if I can barrow another friends camera

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the system is seeing the SD card of the camera. Photorec will only see what the system sees.

If Ubuntu does not see the SD card (which is weird in this times) then maybe trying to connect the SD with another device might help.

Also remember to have the SD already mounted before using photorec on it. Photorec does not automount devices ^^ (I wish it did actually).

So you got those pointers:

1. Make sure Ubuntu see the device.
2. Make your the Device is mounted already and you have access to it via Nautilus for example.
3. Run photorec as root (which it tells you anyway but just in case) to have privilege for some operations photorec will do on the device.

Comment: My bad I should have mentioned that. Ubuntu does recognize the camera is attached. When I plugged it in a pop up automatically opened and asked me what it should do, like open the photo software or folder etc.

And when I open my Home folder under devices the camera is listed

Comment: Ok can you go inside the camera that is shown in the home folder under devices. Also are we talking about ubuntu 11.10 just to make sure?

Comment: Yes I can go into the camera listed under devices, and I can even se epictures on the camera that have not been deleted.

Comment: Also version of ubuntu is 11.10

Comment: Ok just for testing. Go into the device where you can see the pictures. Leav nautilus open in the folder where the pictures are then open the terminal and run photorec. Let me know how it reacts.

Comment: nope photorec still did not see it